# Trying to create Tif from PDF. Getting bad image

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing, itext, tiff

I am trying to create tif image from pdf file, using Itextsharp and Bitmiracle.

First I am trying to get the byte details of each page of pdf file using iTextsharp.

```
string bpp = pd.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString();
PixelFormat pixelFormat;
switch (bpp)
{
    case "1":
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
        break;
    case "8":
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Unknown pixel format {0}.", bpp));
}
```

After that using bitmiracle I am saving that image in a tiff format. But the image is not viewable.

```
string filter = PDFStremObj.Get(PdfName.FILTER).ToString();
switch (filter)
{
    case "/FlateDecode":

    byte[] arr = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((PRStream)PDFStremObj);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Int32.Parse(width), Int32.Parse(height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Int32.Parse(width), Int32.Parse(height)), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, bmd.Scan0, arr.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
    bmp.Save(strFileNewName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
    bmp.Dispose();
    page++;
    break;
}
```

Please help me to fix the problem in the code or suggest me the change.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do people seem to think PDF is an image format? It plain isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe

From there is an option for converting pdf to tiff file or in another files also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can just copy array to bitmap data. The stride may differ, bit depth may differ, byte order may differ, etc etc.
Lajja Thaker posted one of the ways to do it.
Also note that under Windows XP there is no support for some colored tiffs.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmiracle is not a library, [it is a name of a software company](http://bitmiracle.com/), is it libtiff what you were trying to use? Maybe you can contact Bitmiracle for support on the task you are working on.

You cannot create a tiff image from a PDF just by extracting the binary data from it and dumping it into a bitmap object. This is like trying to make an orange juice by squeezing apples.

If you want convert a PDF file into a TIFF image, I would recommend you to use a library that allows you to render the PDF file. Search for [PDF to Image conversion with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PDF+Image++C%23&submit=search) for more details.

If you just want to extract images already compressed as TIFF from within your PDF file, then  you can indeed [extract the binary data](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=284) and save it somewhere else.